# Mouse button pressing on div and move the mouse changes the scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just imagine , we have a div element with static width and height.
The overflow:scroll css cause to scrolling it and scroll bars appears.
If i press mouse button and moving mouse , i want to change the scroll position.

Update : 
Like this site, but here implemented with flash : 
http://www.royalalberthall.com/tickets/default/2013-25-09-1930/29642.aspx

Comment: we're not good at imagining your code.

Comment: @Ejay Ok,so look at the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using http://mootools.net/, it is a nice library

Example: http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Drag.Scroll

Comment: Yes , this is exactly i want. Than you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jquery animate with scrollTop.

Try this code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
     $('div').animate({
         scrollTop : 0  // scroll position
     }, 2000);
 });
```